# ‘checkCudaErrors’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, cuda

I wrote a new CUDA program, but when I compile, I get an error `'checkCudaErrors' was not declared in this scope`. So I added `#include "helper_cuda.h"`,but I still had the same problem.

I opened the file, helper_cuda.h, with Visual Studio Code and found that most of this file is gray. The problem was I did not have the defination `__DRIVER_TYPES_H__`, so I added `#include "driver_types.h"`. But it was useless. In the file, driver_types.h, it showed that I already had the definition `__DRIVER_TYPES_H__`. How can I fix it?

So the real problem is that, the file, driver_tyeps.h, shows I already had the definition of `__DRIVER_TYPES_H__`, but helper_cuda.h shows I don't have the definition.

Comment: Make sure your #includes are in this order:
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define it yourself like this:

```
#define checkCudaErrors(call)                                 \
  do {                                                        \
    cudaError_t err = call;                                   \
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {                                 \
      printf("CUDA error at %s %d: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, \
             cudaGetErrorString(err));                        \
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                     \
    }                                                         \
  } while (0)
```

Comment: In the Cuda samples, it doesn't have the definition of `checkCudaErrors` but I can still use this function. So what I should do to use the function defined in helper_cuda.h instead of defining it myself.

Comment: @hytdt how do you build your program? what is your camke?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved my problem by changing the order of include statement.
At first, my program was like this:

```
    #include "helper_cuda.h"
    #include "driver_types.h"
```

But now, it is:

```
    #include "driver_types.h"
    #include "helper_cuda.h"
```

I don't konw why, but it just works.